# loop in matrix using python

Tags: python, loops, matrix

This is the code that I have:

```
N = 20
matrix = numpy.zeros([3*N,N])
for j in range (N):
    for i in range (2):
        for i1 in range(i*N, (i+1)*N)):
            matrix [i1,j] = numpy.array(readPlotFile['alpha'][0,0,i1-i*N,j]
print(matrix)
```

This code works, and create a matrix(60,20) filled with data from readPlotFile['alpha'][0,0,i1-1*N,j]

What I am trying to do now, is to fill the matrix with:

- from line 0 to line 20: keep filling with readPlotFile['alpha'][0,0,i1-i*n,j]
- from line 21 to line 40: fill the matrix with readPlotFile['alpha'][1,0,i1-i*N,j]
- from line 41 to line 60: fill the matrix with readplotFile['alpha'][5,0,i1-i*n,j]

I was thinking to create a variable or an array named beta = [ 0, 1,5] and write:
`matrix[i1,j] = numpy.array(readPlotFile['alpha'][beta,0,i1-i*N,j]`. How I can create a such loop over beta  to tell the code that from line 0 to line 20, take beta = 0, from line 21 to 40 take beta = 1 and from line 41 to 60 take beta = 5?

Ps: readFile is just a reading file using h5py library, no issue with that!

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use an if statement to do this:

```py
N = 20
matrix = numpy.zeros([3*N,N])
for j in range (N):
    for i in range (2):
        for i1 in range(i*N, (i+1)*N)):
            if j <= 20:
                beta = 0
            elif j <= 40:
                beta = 1
            else:
                beta = 5

            matrix [i1,j] = numpy.array(readPlotFile['alpha'][beta,0,i1-i*N,j]
print(matrix)
```

Alternatively, it seems like you're trying to reshape an array, which could more efficiently be done directly using numpy operations. Check out the [Numpy User Guide intro to reshape operations](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/absolute_beginners.html#can-you-reshape-an-array).

Answer (score 0):

You can do `beta = [0] * 20 + [1] * 20 + [5] * 20`

Comment: Kindly add enough details so that your answer makes sense to future readers.